# Confidence interval for Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, confidence-interval

$X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{n}$ is a random sample from $Poisson(\lambda)$ population.
I need to show that when sample size n is large, the approximate two-sided (1-$\alpha$)% C.I. is
$$
\left[
  \bar{x}
+ \frac{1}{2n} z_{\alpha/2}^2
- \frac{1}{2}
  \sqrt{\left(2\bar{x}+\frac{1}{n}z_{\alpha/2}^2\right)^2-4\bar{x}^2},
  \bar{x}
+ \frac{1}{2n} z_{\alpha/2}^2
+ \frac{1}{2}
  \sqrt{\left(2\bar{x}+\frac{1}{n}z_{\alpha/2}^2\right)^2-4\bar{x}^2}
\right]
$$

I got $\frac{\bar{x}-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda/n}}\sim N(0,1)$ and $\bar{x}\pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\bar{x}/n}$ by myself and found from a [paper](https://www.scirp.org/pdf/OJS20120200001_14971040.pdf) that $\frac{1}{2n}z_{\alpha/2}^2$ is the tail probability for small sample size.

Now I'm confused with $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(2\bar{x}+\frac{1}{n}z_{\alpha/2}^2)^2-4\bar{x}^2}$. From the structure of the equation, I guess it is the error? But I'm not sure about it and have no idea how to get it. Can anyone give me some hints or guide for this part please?

Comment: Perhaps an easier way to express your CI is to let $$m = \bar{x} + \frac{z^2_{\alpha/2}}{2n}$$ and then your CI becomes
$$
\left[m - \sqrt{m^2-\bar{x}^2}, m + \sqrt{m^2-\bar{x}^2}\right]
$$
which sounds like the interval between the roots of the quadratic
$$
r^2/2 - mr + (\bar{x})^2/2
$$